# Does the Kubernetes client-go library contain a function for validating json/yaml files?

Tags: validation, go, kubernetes, kubernetes-go-client

I'd like to know if the client-go library for Kubernetes contains a function that validates if a json/yaml file. Ideally, it would catch errors such as names not being a DNS-1123 compliant or invalid fields specified. It would also be ideal if a list of errors was returned as opposed to the function returning after the first error encountered.

One thought I have tried is doing an exec to call `kubectl --validate --dry-run` but this does not fully validate a manifest (meaning it's possible to pass here but fail when you actually apply the file). It also stops at the first error. Plus, it would get expensive quickly if you have a list of manifests to go through.

Another option I looked at was here [Kubernetes GitHub Issue 193](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/issues/193) but that's not really the appropriate function nor does it do the checks I'm looking for.

Comment: Why don't you just [read the docs](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/client-go) yourself, or [read the source](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/2f45bcbf57f0cfde510a33e7d94a4c89955ff17b/tools/clientcmd/validation.go#L103-L130)?

Comment: I have read the docs and haven't seen anything hence why I'm asking...
The validation.go file you linked is for your cluster configuration, not apps.

Comment: Fine. You can search the rest of the source code as easily as anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Client-go library for Kubernetes contains no validation functions for YAML/JSON configuration files.

But take a look at this [utiliy](https://github.com/garethr/kubeval), you can use it for validation on a client’s side and also use its code as an example of validation implementation.

Answer (score -1):

You can take `k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apis/apps/validation` and `k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apis/core/validation` using this [script](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/79384):

```bash
#!/bin/sh
set -euo pipefail

VERSION=${1#"v"}
if [ -z "$VERSION" ]; then
    echo "Must specify version!"
    exit 1
fi
MODS=($(
    curl -sS https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/v${VERSION}/go.mod |
    sed -n 's|.*k8s.io/\(.*\) => ./staging/src/k8s.io/.*|k8s.io/\1|p'
))
for MOD in "${MODS[@]}"; do
    V=$(
        go mod download -json "${MOD}@kubernetes-${VERSION}" |
        sed -n 's|.*"Version": "\(.*\)".*|\1|p'
    )
    go mod edit "-replace=${MOD}=${MOD}@${V}"
done
go get "k8s.io/kubernetes@v${VERSION}"
```

Than you can write a test like this to validate manifest with a `Service` and `Deployment`:

```golang
import (
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    appsV1 "k8s.io/api/apps/v1"
    coreV1 "k8s.io/api/core/v1"
    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes/scheme"
    kubernetesApps "k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apis/apps"
    kubernetesAppsV1 "k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apis/apps/v1"
    kubernetesAppsValidation "k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apis/apps/validation"
    kubernetesCore "k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apis/core"
    kubernetesCoreV1 "k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apis/core/v1"
    kubernetesCoreValidation "k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apis/core/validation"
    "strings"
    "testing"
    "text/template"
)

const RedisTemplate = `
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  sessionAffinity: None
  ports:
  - name: redis-port
    protocol: TCP
    port: 6379
    targetPort: 6379
--- 
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis
....
`

func Test_RedisManifest(t *testing.T) {
    for _, m := range strings.Split(RedisTemplate, "---") {
        if len(strings.Trim(m, "\n")) == 0 {
            continue
        }

        obj, _, err := scheme.Codecs.UniversalDeserializer().Decode([]byte(m), nil, nil)
        assert.NoError(t, err)
        assert.NotEmptyf(t, obj.GetObjectKind().GroupVersionKind().Kind, "parsed k8s object kind is empty")

        if service, ok := obj.(*coreV1.Service); ok {
            kubernetesService := &kubernetesCore.Service{}
            conversionErr := kubernetesCoreV1.Convert_v1_Service_To_core_Service(service, kubernetesService, nil)
            assert.NoError(t, conversionErr)
            kubernetesService.ObjectMeta.Namespace = "default"
            validationErrs := kubernetesCoreValidation.ValidateService(kubernetesService)
            assert.Empty(t, validationErrs)

        }

        if deployment, ok := obj.(*appsV1.Deployment); ok {
            kubernetesDeployment := &kubernetesApps.Deployment{}
            conversionErr := kubernetesAppsV1.Convert_v1_Deployment_To_apps_Deployment(deployment, kubernetesDeployment, nil)
            assert.NoError(t, conversionErr)

            kubernetesDeployment.ObjectMeta.Namespace = "default"
            validationErrs := kubernetesAppsValidation.ValidateDeployment(kubernetesDeployment, kubernetesCoreValidation.PodValidationOptions{})
            assert.Empty(t, validationErrs)
        }
    }
}
```

I see following disadvantages in this approach:

1. Direct import of `k8s.io/kubernetes` is not recommended by K8s team.
2. Direct import of `k8s.io/kubernetes` can create a troubles in the future.
3. Valdation funcs `ValidateService` and `ValidateDeployment` are expecting that optional fields like `namespace`, `internalTrafficPolicy`, `sessionAffinity` and a lot of others are must have values. Maybe there some other funcs which can fill optional fields with default values but I've not found them on the current moment.